# How to publish a python distribution package to PyPI as part of a Jenkins job by dynamically populating the artifact version?

Tags: python, jenkins, subprocess

I'm trying to publish my package to PyPI as part of my Jenkins build by running:

```
python setup.py sdist --formats zip upload -r Python-hosted
```

In my setup.py, I have:

```
def run_setup():
if is_maven_repository():
    write_version()
setup(
    name='my_project',
    version=read_version(),
    packages=find_packages(
        exclude=[
            'lib', 'lib.*',
            'spark-warehouse',
            'src.data',
            'src.main.java', 'src.main.java.*',
            'src.main.scala', 'src.main.scala.*',
            'src.test', 'src,test.*',
            'target', 'target.*'
        ]
    ),
    url='',
    license='TODO',
    author='',
    author_email='',
    description='',
    long_description=read(
        os.path.join(
            os.getcwd(), 'README.md'
        )
    ),
    install_requires=get_requirements(
        os.path.join(
            os.getcwd(), 'requirements.txt')
    )
)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run_setup()
```

And to get the version dynamically I use:

```
def get_project_version():
return subprocess.check_output(['mvn', 'help:evaluate', '-Dexpression=project.version', '-q', '-DforceStdout'])
```

Locally this works but not on Jenkins. 
Can someone point to the method they use to publish their distribution as part of a Jenkins job? I'd like to get the ${BUILD_ID} and pass it to the python setup.py sdist command, I don't think it's possible.

Thanks in advance.